# method missing on web application classpath

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, maven, classpath

Happy new year!

I'm facing a issue with class-path of web application. I have two maven based modules

1. Api
2. Web app using api

There is a functionality of storing data in api, which works fine without any problem, but when the same method is called from the web application (using tomcat container) it throws the following exception

```
Dec 27, 2012 9:18:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/xyz-service] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFWriterFImpl.setBaseWriterClassName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFWriterFImpl.setBaseWriterClassName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.openjena.riot.SysRIOT.wireIntoJena(SysRIOT.java:93)
    at org.openjena.riot.RIOT.init(RIOT.java:61)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.init(ARQ.java:458)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ARQ.<clinit>(ARQ.java:463)
    at com.ontotext.jena.SesameJena.getContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.ontotext.jena.SesameJena.wireExecution(Unknown Source)
    at com.ontotext.jena.SesameJena.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.ontotext.jena.SesameDataset.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at me.xyz.api.ontoop.service.OWLIMInferencing.getScore(OWLIMInferencing.java:63)
    at me.xyz.service.impl.FacebookRegisterServiceImpl.persistUserInfo(FacebookRegisterServiceImpl.java:109)
    at me.xyz.service.impl.RegisterServiceImpl.registerUseronfirstVist(RegisterServiceImpl.java:40)
    at me.xyz.controller.UserController.validate(UserController.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

When I tried exporting the web app war it has the jar containing class having the method which is reported as not found.

note: All the other classes from api just works fine without any trouble, but only when this particular method is called this issue occurs.

The web application is built using spring, jpa.

Thanks for timely help in advance.
Thank you

Comment: Please add the relevant maven dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hp.hpl.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
```

or possibly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>jena</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
</dependency>
```

You should check if there are no dependency clashes. Probably your webapp is loading an incompatible dependency.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for prompt reply, but I have these dependencies added already to the pom, This functionality just works fine when I call it from a main method, but throws exception when called through spring controller (running as web app)

Comment: You should check if there are no dependency clashes. Probably your webapp is loading an incompatible dependency.

Comment: Thank you asgoth, There  is a dependency clash between Pellet, jena arq. Both uses jena core but a different versions. Exclusion of jena core in pellet dependency did the trick :)

Comment: @Gopalharis I'm having the same issue with Maven, Jena, and Pellet and I can't seem to fix it. Can you share your pom file? How did you "exclude jena core in pellet dependency"? Please help me